# Creating new object of a class in the same class in python?

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

Is it possible to create an new object of a class in itself (in python) ?

In Order to explain the idea more i wrote this code which i don't think that it works.

The new object should be clearly independent from the current object(new attributes etc..)

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        """ Construct an empty linked list. """
        self.first = None
        self.last = None

   def insert_before(self, new_item, next_item):
        """ Insert new_item before next_item. If next_item is None, insert
        new_item at the end of the list. """

        # First set the (two) new prev pointers (including possibly last).
        if next_item is not None:
            new_item.prev = next_item.prev
            next_item.prev = new_item
        else:
            new_item.prev = self.last
            self.last = new_item
        # Then set the (two) new next pointers (including possibly first).
        if new_item.prev is not None:
            new_item.next = next_item
            new_item.prev.next = new_item
        else:
            new_item.next = self.first
            self.first = new_item

    # assuming l1, l2 obj of class node with prev and next (attributes)
    def slice(self, l1, l2):
        curr = l1

        new = LinkedList()
        new.first = l1
        new.last = l2
        if l1.prev is not None:
           l2.prev = l1.prev
        else:
           self.first = l2.next
           self.first.prev = None

        if l2.next is not None:
           l1.next = l2.next
        else:
            self.last = l2.next
        Return new

class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
    """ Construct an item with given value. Also have an id for each item,
    so that we can simply show pointers as ids. """

        Node.num_items += 1
        self.id = Node.num_items
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
    """ Item as human-readable string. In Java or C++, use a function like
    toString(). """

        return "[id = #" + str(self.id) \
           + ", prev = #" + str(0 if self.prev is None else self.prev.id) \
           + ", next = #" + str(0 if self.next is None else self.next.id) \
           + ", val = " + str(self.value) + "]"
```

Comment: The code you are showing does create a completely independent instance of `test`. Although the example is a bit pointless since `test` doesn't have any attributes anyway. Why do you think that it doesn't work? And what do you intend to do with `new`? (Btw, your `__init__` has a syntax error.)

Comment: Your code works fine. Did you try it?

Comment: @5gon12eder because i tried in a real code , and tried to change the attributes values , and did not work

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah i did but not in the same code , i just wrote it to explain my question

Comment: Then please show us code that actually reproduces a problem. It's hard for us to tell what your problem is if we cannot see it. Please also have a look at [mcve] if you haven't done so already.

Comment: You don't need a zillion lines but can you expand this example to the point that it demonstrates the problem? In your current example, for instance, `new` not used or returned so it is discarded. We need more context to help.

Comment: It's useless to post code that looks like your code but doesn't actually illustrate a problem you're having.

Comment: @tdelaney  should i edit the code and add the real code , i wanted to generalize the question

Comment: Please be sure to post a [mcve], not a complete program that you have. Take the time to reduce your code down to the smallest possible size while still exhibiting the behavior that you're asking about.

Comment: It can be your existing test example or real code. The trick is to keep it focused on the problem. If you are doing a bunch of unrelated stuff in your real code, leave it out. Make it easy for us to spot the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley as i said i tried to generalize the question

Comment: Yes. You can create a class instance inside of the class(I am specifically referring to the edit you _just_ made).

Comment: @tdelaney take a look at the new version

Comment: *which i don't think that it works*... Please explain in more detail why not.

Comment: What are `prev` and `next`? Where's the `Node` class. This is not a complete  example, nor is it minimal to demonstrate the question you asked about

Comment: @cricket_007 wow man, ok ill add the Node class

Comment: I'm sorry to sound harsh, but it seems like you could run the code to see if you can or not, ya know?

Comment: @cricket_007 i won't post a question and waste your time if it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147014/discussion-between-james-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an new object of a class in itself (in python) ?

Yes. It is completely possible.

Here is an example:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def make_a(self, value):
        return A(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A({})'.format(self.value)


>>> a = A(10)
>>> a.make_a(15)
A(15)
>>>
```

Now you're probably thinking, *"But the `A` class hasn't been defined yet. Why isn't Python raising a `NameError`?"*  The reason this works it because of the way Python executes your code.

When Python is creating the `A` class, specifically the `make_a` method, it sees that the identifier `A` is being called. It doesn't know whether `A` is a function or class, or even if `A` is *defined*. But it doesn't need to know.

What `A` is exactly is determined at run-time. That is the only time Python checks whether `A` is *really* defined or not.

This is also the reason why you are able to compile a function that references undefined variables:

```
>>> def foo():
    a + b


>>> foo # Python compiled foo...
<function foo at 0x7fb5d0500f28>
>>> foo() # but we can't call it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    foo() # but we can't call it.
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in foo
    a + b
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Glad to help @James.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a deque (double-ended queue) and the slice operation isn't quit right. You need to fixup the prev/next links on the item before l1 and the one after l2.

```
def slice(self, l1, l2):
    new = LinkedList()
    new.first = l1
    new.last = l2
    if l1.prev:
       l1.prev.next = l2.next
    if l2.next:
       l2.next.prev = l1.prev
    l1.prev = l2.next = None
    return new
```

Comment: This does clean up his code. Kudos to that. But this doesn't really seem to answer his _main_ question: _"Is it possible to create an new object of a class in itself (in python) ?"_.

Comment: but i think this will change the list itself . a slice function should give back the wanted part and real list will be updated . for example : list = 
[1, 2, 3, 4]   list.slice(2,3) gives back [2,3] and the list will be then [1,4]

Comment: the idea of the code fine , i found some problems , for example slice(the whole list) or just the first element list(a,a) . i think some more if(s) will do the job

Comment: @james... I took a guess of what OP meant by "slice". If you want to keep the original list, you also need to duplicate all of the nodes to keep the links separate. I think this works for `slice(a,a)` ... or my pencil and paper prototyping failed!